# Chef-Server 12 Getting me errors when the node is not time synced

Tags: chef, ntp, time, time-synchronization, chef-server

I'm getting this error when the clock on my node is different than 15 minutes from my chef server.

Authentication Error:

> Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401). enter code
>   here`The request failed because your clock has drifted by more than 15
>   minutes.
>
> Syncing your clock to an NTP Time source should resolve the issue.

Does Someone know how to change that setting on the server or other method to avoid this check? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue overriding a config on the server. I edited this file **/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb**

```
opscode_erchef['auth_skew] = put your threshold here on seconds
E.g: opscode_erchef['auth_skew] = 43200 (threshold of 12h)
```

With that way to solve, the Web Console, last check-in metric will be wrong, but it works fine.

Comment: Wow, we should probably disallow that. The check is there for security reasons, there is no reason to allow a skew that big and it opens you up to replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If your time is out by more than 15 minutes, you probably don't have any time synchronisation enabled.  You should install your distribution's preferred time synchronisation client (on CentOS/Red Hat it's chrony, on Ubuntu ntp) on both your Chef server and your chef clients.

Comment: I have time synchronization but some nodes are on different time zone.

Comment: Time zones are irrelevant to the kernel and to NTP - they both work in UTC only.